# Sin approximation using Maclaurin expansion

Tags: java, performance, taylor-series

I'm trying to write own code for calculating approximation of rad angle. I works so far for only a specific range of numbers, but fails for large ones like 500 or so.
Additional subquestion: which is more efficient - calculating powers by Math.pow() or the current way of doing it - only multiplication operators.

```
private static double sin_range(double rad) {
    double sin_rad = rad;

    while (sin_rad > 2 * Math.PI) {
        sin_rad -= 2 * Math.PI;
    }
    return sin_rad;
}

private static double approx(double rad, int err) {
    double rad_in_range = sin_range(rad);
    double sin = rad_in_range, r = rad_in_range;
    int previous = 1, factorial = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < err; i++) {

        factorial = (factorial * (previous + 1) * (previous + 2));
        r *= rad * rad;
        if ((i & 1) == 0) { //even
            sin -= r / factorial;
        } else { //odd
            sin += r / factorial;
        }
        previous += 2;
    }

    return sin;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double approximated = approx(15, 5);
    System.out.println(approximated + " = " + Math.sin(15));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `BigDecimal` as they work better with decimal values. And for the second question, use better the `Math.pow()`, the native methods are always optimized (and updated).

Comment: I don't think your series terms are correct.  500! is a very large number indeed.  I would say that you ought to limit the number of terms to match the precision of IEEE double precision floating point numbers.  Those only allow 18 significant digits.  Sine series converges quadratically.  Why ask for 500 terms?

Comment: @duffymo what I mean is approx(500,5), not approx(5,500). I think the problem with this method is just pure maths and how does the sin graph looks like

Comment: No, the problem is bad coding.  Here's what a sine graph looks like: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-sin-cos-tan-graphs.html